# package ‘js-call-r’ is not available for this version of R

Tags: javascript, r

Has anyone had problems installing package ‘js-call-r’?

```
package ‘js-call-r’ is not available for this version of R
"R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)"
```

Comment: According to [here](https://github.com/codejie/js-call-r) the installation procedure is different i.e `npm install --save js-call-r` as it is not a package in CRAN

Comment: `‘js-call-r` does not appear to be an R package, it is a javascript npm package. You cannot run that in R.  At least that's the version that appears at https://github.com/codejie/js-call-r. Or are you trying to use some other package?

Comment: Do I need to run npm install --save js-call-r in JavaScript? Where/how do I run that in JavaScript?

Comment: you might want to approach this via `js` pkg, as `js-call-r` hasn't had any update activity in four years, except for your issue report.